# AWSEBCLI No such file or directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm attempting to run awsebcli from inside a docker image based on amazonlinux

The docker file is like this..

```
FROM amazonlinux:latest

ENV PATH "$PATH:/root/.local/bin"

ADD . /myfiles

WORKDIR /myfiles

#copy credentials
RUN cp -R .aws ~

RUN curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

RUN python get-pip.py --user --no-warn-script-location

RUN pip install awsebcli --upgrade --user

CMD eb --version
```

This just returns:

```
ERROR: OSError - [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What have I missed?

Comment: Are you sure that the error is happening in the `pip install` line?

Comment: Don't `pip install --user`.  Also, don't copy AWS credentials (or any other sort of credentials) into a Docker image: anybody who has the image can easily get the credentials out, and in the case of AWS they can cost you real money.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze - I should have said that the credentials file just has placeholders in it to establish that it isn't the file that is missing.

I removed the --user from pip install but still get 
ERROR: OSError - [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

This was a dumb issue.

I has named the elastic beanstalk config file just "config" (like the .aws/config)

It was supposed to be called .elasticbeanstalk/config.yml

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it turned out that in my configuration file under **.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml** I had the following line

```
sc: git
```

This makes the **eb** tool search for a **.git** which was not present in my case since I only wanted to deploy a zip file.

The error message is far from clear !